# How to find EventSystem component on a GameObject in the scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
private EventSystem myEventSystem;

public static GameNotes Instance { get; private set; }

private void Awake()
{
    if (Instance == null)
    {
        Instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

        // Initialize your notes or load from file
        savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "notes.txt");
        LoadFromFile(); // Load notes if they exist
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject); // Ensure only one instance exists
    }

    myEventSystem = GetComponentInChildren<EventSystem>(true);
}
```

myEventSystem is null.

this screenshot shows where the Eventsystem is in the scene.  and this script is attached to GameNotes GameObject.

[image: event system]

i want to get the EventSystem object the gameobject and also the component. both.

using GetComponentInChildren is bnot working, myEventSystem is null.

Comment: game notes has no children, so no, it wont find the component in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T GetComponentInChildren<T>(bool includeInactive)` gets the first child's component of type `T`, if not found, gets it from the parent, otherwise returns null. It won't work unless you use this method on a parent `Component` with a child which has the desired component.

```
EventSystem Parent
  EventSystem
```

```cs
eventSystem = eventSystemParent.GetComponentInChildren<EventSystem>();
```

Your `EventSystem` doesn't have a parent, so it won't work in your case.
The best option is to use `T FindObjectOfType<T>(bool includeInactive) where T : Object`, which finds the first `Component` of type `T` in the scene, otherwise returns `null`.

```cs
eventSystem = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<EventSystem>(includeInactive: false);
```

You can avoid `GameObject.` if you run this in `MonoBehavior`, as it derives from `GameObject`

```cs
eventSystem = FindObjectOfType<EventSystem>(includeInactive: false);
```

This finds the desired `eventSystem`, assuming you have just one in the scene and it's active. Make sure to change the parameter to `true` if it's active. If you have more than one `EventSystem` in your scene, consider using a `tag` check, while also finding all `EventSystems` in your scene.

```cs
foreach (EventSystem system in FindObjectsOfType<EventSystem>(includeInactive: false))
    if (system.CompareTag("BestEventSystem"))
        eventSystem = system;
```

Or faster with `LINQ`:

```cs
eventSystem = FindObjectsOfType<EventSystem>(includeInactive: false)
    .First(s => s.CompareTag("BestEventSystem"));
```